# Is there anyway in crontab to excute first non-monday after day 5?

Tags: linux, cron

As stated in the title, I am having troubles to set that condition in order to be processed by crontab with the traditional definition

```
 ┌────────── minute (0 - 59)
 │ ┌──────── hour (0 - 23)
 │ │ ┌────── day of month (1 - 31)
 │ │ │ ┌──── month (1 - 12)
 │ │ │ │ ┌── day of week (0 - 6 => Sunday - Saturday, or
 │ │ │ │ │                1 - 7 => Monday - Sunday)
 ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓
 * * * * * command to be executed
```

The process must be excuted on day 5 every month, but in order to avoid the tuesday midnight weekly server reset, I must check if day 5 is monday and if so wait till the next day to execute it.

When testing on crontab.guru, what I understand that 5-6 is an and condition (executed both days) and adding a 2 at the end adds tuesday condition (regardless if that tuesday is on the specified dates). Right?

[image]

Any idea of how to achieve this?
Thx in advance.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1104605/run-crontab-in-specific-day-but-only-if-is-in-specific-weekday

Comment: Useful, thx! Is just the kind of "inside checks" that i was trying to avoid, but if there isn't any other way...